# how to create a Twig nested loop in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm working with symfony 2 I have the following code in Twig

```
        {% for entity in entities1 %}
            {{ entity.id }}
            {% for ul in userlike %}
                {%  if entity.id == ul.images_id %}
                    {{ ul.username }}
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
```

The inner loop is performed only once !!
And the output is as follows :

85 mali user1 mina 
84 
83 
75 
74 
73 
72 
71

To solve this problem, what solution do you recommend?

Comment: are you sure is only performed one due to a "twig limitation"? I suppose that your if statement is failing. Could you try to insert an else statement and print something else to be sure that inner lopp is executed only once?

Comment: i bet it's due to the `if` statement inside the second loop. try to test without it

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop isn't performed only once, it is just that your condition within the loop is only satisfied once, i.e. on the first iteration. In other words, entity 84 matches several image_ids, but your remaining entity IDs do not match any image_ids